# Pandas taking value based on previous value in a different column

Tags: python, pandas

It may be simple, but for some reason I can't think of a good way to solve it.

So, let's say this is my DataFrame:

```
     a    b 
0   99    3
1   99    56
2    1    7
3    1    80  
4    1    55
5    2    601
6    2    -4
7    1    33
8    1    22
```

I would like to create a new column, `c`, where the values will be the last value of `b` in the previous value of `a`, so the output should be:

```
     a    b      c
0   99    3     nan
1   99    56    nan
2    1    7     56
3    1    80    56  
4    1    55    56
5    2    601   55
6    2    -4    55
7    1    33    -4
8    1    22    -4
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are `a` values always increasing?

Comment: No, I'll edit the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would compare `df['a']` to its shift to identify value changes, and `ffill()` with `shift()`:

```
df['c'] = df.loc[df['a'] != df['a'].shift(-1),'b']
df['c'] = df['c'].ffill().shift()
```

Output:

```
    a    b     c
0  99    3   NaN
1  99   56   NaN
2   1    7  56.0
3   1   80  56.0
4   1   55  56.0
5   2  601  55.0
6   2   -4  55.0
7   1   33  -4.0
8   1   22  -4.0
```

Comment: Same groups of `a` can occur multiple times, I edited my example to emphasize that.

Answer (score 3):

You could use also `where` with `diff`

```py
In [73]: df['b'].where(df['a'].diff(-1).ne(0)).shift().ffill()
Out[73]: 
0     NaN
1     NaN
2    56.0
3    56.0
4    56.0
5    55.0
6    55.0
7    -4.0
8    -4.0
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

---

```
In [74]: df['c'] = df['b'].where(df['a'].diff(-1).ne(0)).shift().ffill()

In [75]: df
Out[75]: 
    a    b     c
0  99    3   NaN
1  99   56   NaN
2   1    7  56.0
3   1   80  56.0
4   1   55  56.0
5   2  601  55.0
6   2   -4  55.0
7   3   33  -4.0
8   3   22  -4.0
```