# create values on one column based on values in another column based on group

Tags: python, pandas

I asked a similar question today [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555091/pandas-taking-value-based-on-previous-value-in-a-different-column), I thought it would be easy to apply it to groups, but I find it harder than I thought.

So, let's say this is my DataFrame:

```
   group   a     b 
0    0    'a'    3
1    0    'a'    56
2    0    'b'    7
3    0    'b'    80  
4    0    'b'    55
5    0    'f'    601
6    0    'f'    -4
7    0    'g'    33
8    0    'g'    22
9    1    'a'    3
10   1    'a'    56
11   1    'b'    7
12   1    'b'    80  
13   1    'b'    55
14   1    'f'    601
15   1    'f'    -4
16   1    'g'    33
17   1    'g'    22
```

I would like to create a new column, `c`, where the values will be the last value of `b` in the previous value of `a`, *in the same group*,  so the output should be:

```
   group   a    b      c
0    0    'a'    3     nan
1    0    'a'    56    nan
2    0    'b'    7     56
3    0    'b'    80    56  
4    0    'b'    55    56
5    0    'f'    601   55
6    0    'f'    -4    55
7    0    'g'    33    -4
8    0    'g'    22    -4
9    1    'a'    3     nan
10   1    'a'    56    nan
11   1    'b'    7     56
12   1    'b'    80    56  
13   1    'b'    55    56
14   1    'f'    601   55
15   1    'f'    -4    55
16   1    'g'    33    -4
17   1    'g'    22    -4
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Does your `df` have duplicated index?

Comment: no Sorry, simple ctrl+v lazyness, I'll fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work if your data does not have duplicated index:

```
groups = df.groupby('group')
df['c'] = df.loc[df['a']!=groups['a'].shift(-1),'b']
df['c'] = groups['c'].ffill()
df['c'] = groups['c'].shift()
```

Output:

```
    group    a    b     c
0       0  'a'    3   NaN
1       0  'a'   56   NaN
2       0  'b'    7  56.0
3       0  'b'   80  56.0
4       0  'b'   55  56.0
5       0  'f'  601  55.0
6       0  'f'   -4  55.0
7       0  'g'   33  -4.0
8       0  'g'   22  -4.0
9       1  'a'    3   NaN
10      1  'a'   56   NaN
11      1  'b'    7  56.0
12      1  'b'   80  56.0
13      1  'b'   55  56.0
14      1  'f'  601  55.0
15      1  'f'   -4  55.0
16      1  'g'   33  -4.0
17      1  'g'   22  -4.0
```

If you data does have duplicated index as shown in the sample, you can do:

```
# save the index
idx = df.index

# remove the index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

groups = df.groupby('group')
df['c'] = df.loc[df['a']!=groups['a'].shift(-1),'b']
df['c'] = groups['c'].ffill()
df['c'] = groups['c'].shift()

# put the index back
df.index = idx
```